# Manually changing URL alias values via phpmyadmin? What does this affect?

Tags: 7, path-aliases, database

I have a bunch of aliases in my url_alias table. I want to change the source of certain rows, but I'm not sure if it would affect anything. What I need to know is if the column **PID** in the url_alias table is linked to anything else. Currently I just want to switch node/33 to node/2343, but im afraid I might break something if im doing it via phpmyadmin. I can't do it via the site as I have over 100+ entries I have to modify. The easiest way is by doing it in mysql.

Also is there a drupal database table map I can generate that shows me how each table is linked to each other?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing **any** manual updates to the Drupal database is a bad idea unless you know exactly what you are doing.

The `{url_alias}` table is written to with [`path_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/path_save/7).  If you look at the source, two hooks may be fired, depending on whether the path is new or update: [`hook_path_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!path!path.api.php/function/hook_path_insert/7) or [`hook_path_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!path!path.api.php/function/hook_path_update/7).

So, if you update  `{url_alias}` manually, you don't give any other modules the chance to react via the hooks.  Whether or not anything bad will happen depends on whether *your* system has any of these hooks in use.  Off the top of my head, I am unaware of any modules that do, but you would need to run a [`module_implements('path_insert')`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_implements/7) and `module_implements('path_update')` to be sure.

Your safest bet is to always use the API.  Write a standalone script, and execute it with `drush -u 1 scr yourscrpt.php` to make sure all of your hooks execute.